# Passing an object to custom view in Google maps SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have custom view (a nib with its class) that I show when user taps on map marker. I also have an array of objects from where I'd like to show data of selected object when user taps on one of the markers. I create markers from the same array in a separate method. How to I get my element in array (to show additional data) when user taps the marker ? Or is there another way to get the object from array based on pressed marker. Apart from regexing based on lon and lat etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding my model to

```
marker.userData
```

example:

```
func addMarkers(){

    for place in places{

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        let placeLat = place.latitude
        let placeLon = place.longitude
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(placeLat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(placeLon))
        marker.appearAnimation = .pop
        marker.map = mpView
        marker.userData = place

    }

}
```

Then later I access it in:

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

```
    let title = (marker.userData as! placeModel).name
    let add = (marker.userData as! placeModel).address
    let id = (marker.userData as! placeModel).id
    let image = (marker.userData as! placeModel).image
    let imageAddressInDocuments = ("\(getDocumentsDirectory())\(image)")
    print("image address in documents %@", imageAddressInDocuments )
    var infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("custView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! custView
    infoWindow.titleLabel.text = title
    infoWindow.addressLabel.text = add
    infoWindow.restaurantImage.image = image != "" ? UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageAddressInDocuments) : UIImage(named: "addImage")


    return infoWindow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> GMSMapViewDelegate has the delegate function which lets you to return
>   your customView as info window.

```
optional public func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView?
```

You have to subclass GSMarker which takes your model in init.

```
class MapItem:GMSMarker {
    var model: Model!  //your data model
    init(data: Model) {
        super.init()
        // pass cordinate
        self.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: data.latitude!, longitude: data.longitude!) 
        // pass Model
        self.model = data 
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    // Wrap GSMarker to your custom marker which is MapItem here
    let customMarker = marker as! MapItem 
      // pass your model to CustomView(marker info window) in init 
    let customView = CustomView(markerModel: customMarker.model)
    return customView
}
```

Comment: Hi I am using that method, but how do I connect my selected marker with an element from my array so that I can display certain data from my element.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense. I presume I also need to write an initializer in my custom view for
     let customView = CustomView(markerModel: customMarker.model)

Comment: Yes you should wirte the init and populate you model's data in the Custom View